# C# WPF If two Rectangles with different background colors overlap completely, the border of the Rectangele below will appear

Tags: wpf, xaml

I use Rectangle and button to do the test, but the results are not the same

I want to overlap two rectangles of different colors, and i don't want see the rectangle below, but this is not the case.

[image: Using Rectangle]

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Border>
        <Canvas x:Name="Pad">

                <Rectangle Height="100"
                           Width="100"
                           Fill="Red"  
                           Canvas.Left="10" 
                           ClipToBounds="True"
                           Canvas.Top="10"
                           >
                </Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Height="100"
                           Width="100" 
                           Fill="White"  
                           Canvas.Left="10" 
                           Canvas.Top="10">
                </Rectangle>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: Using Button]
If I use two buttons to overlap, I will not see the border below. Why is the result of using rectangle and button different ?

```xml
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Border>
           <Canvas x:Name="Pad">
                <Button Height="100"
                        Width="100"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="Red"  
                        Canvas.Left="10" 
                        ClipToBounds="True"
                        Canvas.Top="10">
                </Button>
                <Button Height="100"
                        Width="100" 
                        Background="White"  
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Canvas.Left="10" 
                        Canvas.Top="10">
                </Button>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could be because of anti-aliasing. Be aware that WPF drawing units are typically not identical to screen pixels.

Comment: What does "Why use Rectangle to appear?" mean ???

Comment: "I can't see the rectangle below, but this is not the case." - Can you or can you not see the rectangle?

Comment: @Clemens I will try  it  thanks 
 I have changed  it sorry

Comment: @Enigmativity  I have changed it  sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I use   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" to solve the problem

```
      <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <Border>
                <Canvas x:Name="Pad">
    
                        <Rectangle Height="100"
                                   Width="100"
                                   Fill="Red"  
                                   Canvas.Left="10" 
                                   ClipToBounds="False"
                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                   Canvas.Top="10">
    
                      
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle Height="100"
                                       Width="100" 
                                       Fill="White"  
                                     SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                       Canvas.Left="10" 
                                       Canvas.Top="10">
    
                        </Rectangle>
    
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

**Update**
The result after use:

[image: The result after use]

Comment: @Jeff  It works for me ，but  I don't know why have different result for we

Comment: Different screens.  I run two 4K monitors @ 100%.  Different calculations for each.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seem to go away if ClipToBounds="False" is set for both Rectangles.

Comment: thanks your reply ， i tried it for your way  but still have same problem.

Comment: You added to both rectangles?

Comment: Yes , I added to both rectangles.

Comment: There appears to be an inaccuracy between the fill and stroke.  When zoomed in to 6400%, I see two perimeter lines but with the buttons I see only one.  I found a way to eliminate the left over line but, I fear, will not suit your preference.  I set the stroke thickness for both rectangles to 1 and set their color to the background color.   I no longer see the left over lines but this is not an ideal answer.